# KVM vm network performance is super slow compared to host

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I am running a KVM Windows 11 VM guest with an arch linux host. I have tried across multiple windows and linux guests and the network performance is the same across the guests, so this is not a guest issue. I am using a NAT NIC with virtio as the driver an I have the appropriate VirtIO drivers installed on the guests.

Network on host: ~150down/6up

Network on guest: ~20down/6up

(Both via speed test. Measured in mbps)

Some possibly useful info:

ip link (on host)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp45s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:45:06:87:3e:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:1d:96:91:e2:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:9d:67:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master virbr0 state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:4f:74:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The NIC uses the default network created by virt manager. I have tried both the default NAT and a bridged `virbr0` device. Both have similarly bad performance. My host is connected via wifi using the `wlp0s20f3` device.

Any reason for such a severe network drop? I will edit in any other requested information.

Edit: To test if NCI emulation may be creating problems, I hosted a simple python server on my host with `py -m http.server 8000` and downloaded a large file on my guest. This allowed me to achieve ~600 MB/s. The same was true when hosting a server on the guest and downloading on the host. Thus, I have concluded NIC emulation is not bottlenecking networking performance. At least not for my needs. So this must be a problem with some setting, but I cannot find anything on it online.

Edit 2: I have switched from dhcpcd and wifi-menu to network manager. Nothing has changed. Perhaps this is helpful information. I also read somewhere to disable packet coalescing, but that did nothing.

Comment: @A.B Yup, I have the virtio option selected for device model in my machine settings. I also have the drivers installed on the guest.

Comment: @A.B I also just tested this by transferring data between the guest and host, and it seems to be fast enough. I've edited in more details.

Comment: Can this be an MTU problem? Does `ping -s 1472 $some_internet_ip` work (on a VM)?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Hi. Running the given command in my windows guest cmd, I receive the error `Bad value for option -s, valid range is from 1 to 4`

Comment: As you're also using Linux guests, you could use the command on a Linux guest so it behaves as expected?